Quicksort 3-way paritition vs 2-way partition
I know 3-way partition variation of quicksort is best choice for arrays with large numbers of duplicate, but I don't clearly figure out that is 3-way as good as 2-way when there is no duplicate key?

Why would it be? Who said that it was?

@YvesDaoust If not why 3-way is popular choice for sort libraries (e.g. java system sort)?

Is this meant to be a statistic?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941447/quicksort-with-3-way-partition

There is classical counting comparisons&swaps (don't ignore Hoare's "split swap" variant). And there is taking into account hierarchical memory.

Concrete analysis of algorithms is hard and often tedious. The literature for this particular algorithm is brief and unclear. In particular I cannot find any formal analysis of the special case with duplicates. However, there are some results for the uniform case.
Vladimir Yaroslavsky, the author of the Dual Pivot Quicksort in the JDK, claims that the dual-pivot algorithm always performs better. See his write up:

It is proved that for the Dual-Pivot Quicksort the average number of comparisons is 2nln(n), the average number of swaps is 0.8nln(n), whereas classical Quicksort algorithm has 2nln(n) and 1nln(n) respectively. Full mathematical investigation has been done and will be copied here (TBD).

Okay that TODO is pretty horrifying. Let's see what else is out there.
In Wild, Nebel, Neininger 2013 the authors analyze both the Dual Pivot and Single Pivot Quicksort algorithms under uniformly random input. The analysis is involved! But the big pay-off is on pp. 24 where there is a table of results. The paper analyzes some other metrics in detail, but let's look at swaps for comparison with the above:

Expected number of swaps:
Dual Pivot: 0.6 n ln(n) + O(n)
Single Pivot: 0.33 n ln(n) + O(n)

There is some room to argue about choosing a parameter, but this does not support Yaroslavsky's purported analysis. I'm reasonably confident in this result, the paper was published in TALG. Further, the fact that the analysis took 23 pages of gnarly recurrences makes me rather skeptical that Yaroslavsky's claimed proof didn't fit in the margins so to speak.
